# Como verificar si la letra ingresada está en algún elemento del array?

Tags: javascript

Estoy intentando hacer un buscador, tal que al ir ingresando la *busqueda en el input*, debería mostrar las coincidencias por consola, en el código explico lo que intento hacer además, pero no me funciona, **por qúe? y como solucionarlo ?**

```js
var objetosDisponibles = [
  
  "zapatillas",
  "gorros",
  "materiales",
  "lentes"
  
];

  var b = document.getElementById('buscador');
  b.addEventListener('keyup',function(e){
    var letra = 'which' in e ? String.fromCharCode(e.which) : String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode);
    var max = objetosDisponibles.length; // Largo del array
    var indiceActual = 0; // Indice, para saber en que numero de letra va escribiendo en el buscado,
    /* Ejemplo: Si quiere escribir 'zapatillas' y recién va en la 'z', el indice es 0, entonces buscará:
    objetosDisponibles[largo del input del buscador] y si coincide con la letra que se ingresa, mostrara la coincidencia */
    
    for(let j=0;j<max;j++){
      if(objetosDisponibles[b.value.length-1] == letra) { 
        console.log(objetosDisponibles[b.value.length-1]);
      }
    }
    
  });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  
  <label style="font-family:monospace;font-size:20px;" for="buscador">Buscar:</label>
<input style="border-radius:9px;" type="text" id="buscador">
 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

> No me funciona, por qúe? y como solucionarlo ?

La condición:

`if(objetosDisponibles[b.value.length-1] == letra)`

no tiene sentido, puesto que estás chequeando igualdad entre un caracter y una palabra.

Por un lado tienes `letra`, que es el caracter ingresado en el input, puede ser "Z", "a", etc.

Por otro lado el elemento en la posición `[b.value.length-1]` del array `objetosDisponibles`, estos elementos no son caracteres sino palabras ("zapatillas", "gorros", etc)

De todas formas, me parece mas sencillo utilizar [String.includes()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_includes.asp) para determinar si algun elemento de `objetosDisponibles` contiene como subcadena el texto ingresado en el buscador.

He utilizado [Array.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) para filtrar los elementos que contengan la subcadena indicada, por ejemplo para la subcadena "za" obtendrás como resultado:

```
[
  "zapatillas",
  "zanahorias"
]
```

```js
var objetosDisponibles = [
  
  "zapatillas",
  "zanahorias",
  "gorros",
  "gorilas",
  "materiales",
  "lentes"
  
];

  var b = document.getElementById('buscador');
  b.addEventListener('keyup',function(e){
    var similars = objetosDisponibles.filter(function(objeto){
      return objeto.includes(b.value);
    });
    console.log(similars);
  });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  
  <label style="font-family:monospace;font-size:20px;" for="buscador">Buscar:</label>
<input style="border-radius:9px;" type="text" id="buscador">
 
</body>
</html>
```